# A persistent lookup table in PHP

Tags: php

I am building an application that takes a string of text, something like 'ABCD', and then performs a variety of transformations on it and returns a result in the form of a boolean as to whether or not the string, after being converted to a standard format, meets certain criteria.

For my use case, there are ~8,000 unique keys after converting the string to a standard format. This means that, instead of performing all of the evaluations every time I convert a string, I could simply create a lookup table with the standardized strings as the key and the result as the pair.

The distinction may seem somewhat trivial, but performance is incredibly important because my users are uploading 50k-270k strings at a time and they will be doing this multiple times a day, and I need to be able to return the results for 270k strings practically in real time. Querying a MySQL database 50k-270k times seems even much more inefficient than just performing the operations every single time. What is the missing piece to my puzzle? Is there a way to programmatically create a sort of persistent lookup table inside the language itself that I can access over and over?

On the one hand I know I can create a memoized array programmatically by creating a script that runs the functions on every combination of standardized string, but I don't know how to make this persist over time so I don't need to do this on every upload. Likewise, I know how to do this in MySQL but I can imagine the sheer number of individual queries would make that a terrible option. Where is the middle ground?

Comment: This sounds like a great job for an SQL database to handle. I can't imagine it would introduce that much overhead, and it is, in essence, a persistent key/value table.

Comment: @David And just to make sure we're on the same page, that is considering that each time the user uploads a new file I will be making 50k-270k individual select queries, correct? Just want to make sure I'm not ignorant of some alternative use of MySQL for large lookups. If so, I'll give it a go now building it out this way and see how it looks.

Comment: Well I mean one thing you could do is store all the key/value pairs in an SQL database and once you get a new file, `SELECT` all of the records and load them into a PHP array by key/value and evaluate the file against the PHP array. It might save you a tiny amount of time if the data is in a local array vs using MySQL commands, but I don't know that it would make much of a difference, if any.

Comment: @David Actually, loading all of the values in like that makes total sense. That was essentially what I was looking for. I'm surprised that it might not make a big difference, but this was at least what I wanted to try. Thanks a ton, I'll report back with the results.

Comment: This is what database indexes are for. If you do what @David suggests you're just going to wind up trying to build an index in PHP and it will be awful. Just do the queries. Better yet, gate this behind some sort of batch processing system and use a queue and parallel workers so you're not waiting for thousands of queries to be answered serially.